# How to set an HTTP Basic Auth header in Selenide - have to use corporate proxy as well

Tags: selenium-webdriver, basic-authentication, selenide

I need to switch Basich Auth in custom client framework that use Selenide for E2E Testing from Basic URL Auth to Basic Auth with http header. The framework already uses corporate http proxy with Basic Auth, selenium Grid 4.5.0 and Selenide 6.9.0.

My understanding of Selenide documentation:
If `selenideConfig.proxyEnabled(true)` is set, I can use

```
driver.open(selenideConfig.baseUrl(), AuthenticationType.BASIC, new BasicAuthCredentials("", username, password));
```

That should start Selenide Built-in Proxy and set basic Auth header over built-in proxy.

As result I got: *This Site cannot be reached!*

If I set `selenideConfig.proxyEnabled(false)` test works but with URL basic auth.
I thought that chaining built-in and corporate proxy like this could be an fix:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setAutodetect(false);
proxy.setHttpProxy("http://corUser:corPass@corporate.proxy.com");
proxy.setSslProxy("http://corUser:corPass@corporate.proxy.com");

SelenideProxyServerFactory proxyServerFactory = new DefaultSelenideProxyServerFactory();
SelenideProxyServer selenideProxyServer = proxyServerFactory.create(selenideConfig, proxy);
WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver.getWebDriver(), selenideProxyServer);
```

But I still can’t access a webpage. *This Site cannot be reached!*

How to do this a proper way? What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research, I found a solution that works for mi use case. I’m not using BrowserUpProxy though. The key point hire is that BrowserMobProxy must run on a same Host as Selenium Grid as well as executed Tests, so I switched from Classic Selenium Grid to WebDriverManager and browser in Docker.
The following code works with this setup.

```
proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
proxy.autoAuthorization(host, username, password, AuthType.BASIC);
proxy.chainedProxyAuthorization(System.getenv("proxy_user"), System.getenv("proxy_password"), AuthType.BASIC);
proxy.setChainedProxy(new InetSocketAddress("proxy.example.com ", 8080));
proxy.start(0); 

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.setProxy(ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy));

wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker().capabilities(options).enableVnc();
driver = wdm.create();
WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
```